# ExpressJS + PassportJS: Facebook and Twitter referrer link?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, facebook-login, twitter-login

Basic scenario: Referrer URL - https://example.com/5a936e07df429a4bb3dd7d29

User can login using `/auth/facebook` or `/auth/twitter` route. After they are sent to the provider and get redirect back to my site using the `/auth/facebook/callback` or `/auth/twitter/callback`.

I have no clue how to redirected them to https://example.com/5a936e07df429a4bb3dd7d29 after they have successfully logged in. ATM they are all redirect to `('/')` which is not the desired url.

Any ideas ?

```
//FACEBOOK
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['email', 'user_location'] }));
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/' }), (req, res) => { res.redirect('/'); });

//TWITTER
app.get('/auth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'));
app.get('/auth/twitter/callback', passport.authenticate('twitter', { failureRedirect: '/' }), (req, res) => { res.redirect('/'); });

/**
 * Sign in with Facebook.
 */
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_SECRET,
  callbackURL: '/auth/facebook/callback',
  profileFields: ['name', 'email', 'link', 'locale', 'timezone', 'gender'],
  passReqToCallback: true
}, (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
   console.log('hellow' + req.baseUrl + req.path + ' aiiiiiciiii');
   console.log(req.header('referrer'));
   console.log('\n');
   console.log(req.originalUrl + ' aici e full pathul');
  if (req.user) {
    User.findOne({ facebook: profile.id }, (err, existingUser) => {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (existingUser) {
        req.flash('errors', { msg: 'There is already a Facebook account that belongs to you. Sign in with that account or delete it, then link it with your current account.' });
        done(err);
      } else {

        User.findById(req.user.id, (err, user) => {
          if (err) { return done(err); }
          user.facebook = profile.id;
          user.tokens.push({ kind: 'facebook', accessToken });
          user.profile.name = user.profile.name || `${profile.name.givenName} ${profile.name.familyName}`;
          user.profile.gender = user.profile.gender || profile._json.gender;
          user.profile.picture = user.profile.picture || `https://graph.facebook.com/${profile.id}/picture?type=large`;

          user.save((err) => {
            req.flash('info', { msg: 'Facebook account has been linked.' });
            done(err, user);
          });
        });

      }
    });
  } else {
    User.findOne({ facebook: profile.id }, (err, existingUser) => {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (existingUser) {
        return done(null, existingUser);
      }
      User.findOne({ email: profile._json.email }, (err, existingEmailUser) => {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (existingEmailUser) {
          req.flash('errors', { msg: 'There is already an account using this email address. Sign in to that account and link it with Facebook manually from Account Settings.' });
          done(err);
        } else {
          const user = new User();
          user.email = profile._json.email;
          user.facebook = profile.id;
          user.tokens.push({ kind: 'facebook', accessToken });
          user.profile.name = `${profile.name.givenName} ${profile.name.familyName}`;
          user.profile.gender = profile._json.gender;
          user.profile.picture = `https://graph.facebook.com/${profile.id}/picture?type=large`;
          user.profile.location = (profile._json.location) ? profile._json.location.name : '';

          user.wishlists = WishListCreator(user.id);

          user.save((err) => {
            done(err, user);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
}));

// Sign in with Twitter.

passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
  consumerKey: process.env.TWITTER_KEY,
  consumerSecret: process.env.TWITTER_SECRET,
  callbackURL: '/auth/twitter/callback',
  passReqToCallback: true
}, (req, accessToken, tokenSecret, profile, done) => {
  if (req.user) {
    User.findOne({ twitter: profile.id }, (err, existingUser) => {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (existingUser) {
        req.flash('errors', { msg: 'There is already a Twitter account that belongs to you. Sign in with that account or delete it, then link it with your current account.' });
        done(err);
      } else {
        User.findById(req.user.id, (err, user) => {
          if (err) { return done(err); }
          user.twitter = profile.id;
          user.tokens.push({ kind: 'twitter', accessToken, tokenSecret });
          user.profile.name = user.profile.name || profile.displayName;
          user.profile.location = user.profile.location || profile._json.location;
          user.profile.picture = user.profile.picture || profile._json.profile_image_url_https;
          user.save((err) => {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            req.flash('info', { msg: 'Twitter account has been linked.' });
            done(err, user);
          });
        });
      }
    });
  } else {
    User.findOne({ twitter: profile.id }, (err, existingUser) => {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (existingUser) {
        return done(null, existingUser);
      }
      const user = new User();
      // Twitter will not provide an email address.  Period.
      // But a person’s twitter username is guaranteed to be unique
      // so we can "fake" a twitter email address as follows:
      user.email = `${profile.username}@twitter.com`;
      user.twitter = profile.id;
      user.tokens.push({ kind: 'twitter', accessToken, tokenSecret });
      user.profile.name = profile.displayName;
      user.profile.location = profile._json.location;
      user.profile.picture = profile._json.profile_image_url_https;

      user.wishlists = WishListCreator( user.id );

      user.save((err) => {

        done(err, user);
      });
    });
  }
}));
```

Comment: BUMP ? really no one ?

Comment: Why not just chabge res.redirect to the desired route?